# Play RTP video stream using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, video-streaming, gstreamer

I want to create a Qt widget that can play incoming RTP streams where the video is encoded as H264 and contains no audio.

My basic plan for implementation is this:

- Create a Phonon [MediaSource](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/phonon-mediasource.html) object (Stream type).
- Connect it with a [QIODevice](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qiodevice.html) subclass that provides the data
- Obtain the video data using either:

  - The [JRTPLIB](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib) client library
  - The [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) [gstrtpbin](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-gstrtpbin.html) plugin. This plugin takes care depayloading the packages and decoding the video. Maybe this improves the chances that Phonon will recognize the data.

My environment:

- Ubuntu 9.10
- Qt 4.6

My questions:

- Is my approach a good one? Perhaps I'm overlooking a more obvious or simple solution?
- I'm currently experiencing this issue: when trying to play the video stream the state of the MediaObject turns to ErrorState with errorType FatalError. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit**
One solution I found is using libVLC in combination with Qt, which I learned about in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873113/how-to-implement-a-video-widget-in-qt-that-builds-upon-gstreamer). Here's a [code sample](http://code.google.com/p/stacked-crooked/source/browse/trunk/Playground/QtWithLibVLC/VLCPlayer.cpp) for the interested.
I'm still looking for a Phonon-based solution.

Ideally I would only need to provide an SDP file and job is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using the libVLC solution. I can't garantuee that this is the *best* solution though as I simply stopped looking after that.

Here's a [link to the libVLC sample](http://code.google.com/p/stacked-crooked/source/browse/trunk/Playground/QtWithLibVLC/).

Comment: It looks like you have taken this file down. Any chance of posting the code again, or has it been lost to time?

Comment: @StackedCrooked anyway to get stream from an IP Cam using the files?

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand Phonon works at least in Windows is that QT provides a phonon backend plugin for DirectShow (\plugins\phonon_backend\phonon_ds94.dll) and GStreamer in your case.  Then you would either obtain or write your own DirectShow filter which can accept RTP streams as a source.  DirectShow takes care of the decoding, and Phonon will take care of the rendering.

So if the backend works, the application code is as simple as:

```
        Phonon::MediaObject *media = new Phonon::MediaObject();
        Phonon::VideoWidget *video = new Phonon::VideoWidget();
        Phonon::createPath(media, video);
        media->setCurrentSource(source);
        media->play();
```

Seems that the problem lies with the GStreamer backend accepting RTP as a source.  Can you playback that source in standalone GStreamer without any problems?

Comment: I haven't managed to make it work yet. Playing a local file works, but when I try to load an RTP stream (through a MediaSource(QIODevice) object that read RTP packets) the VideoPlayer stays in LoadingState.

Right now I am experimenting with another approach: I'm using GStreamer's gstrtpbin plugin to read incoming RTP data, decode the video stream and somehow connect it to a Qt widget.