# FBDEV(0): FBIOPUTCMAP: Invalid argument error in Xorg.0.log file

Tags: linux, qt, video, graphics, kernel

My Qt application which plays video shows just a blank `VideoWidget` window.
When I remove my `Xorg.conf` file from `/etc/X11/` directory on my Debian Jessie 8.2 and restart system, video starts to play, but there is a lack of colors on whole display.

```
- Kernel version is: 4.1.15-ti-rt-r40 
- Platform: BeagleBone Black
```

I found this error reported as a bug on [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-fbdev/+bug/573668), but it is very old thread. Is problem in graphic card drivers built for this BB under Debian Jessie 8.2?

Comment: This is related to color depth configuration built with Qt and color depth in xorg.conf, do you build Qt with -depths? what are color depths in your xorg.conf?

Comment: @Marware It tells me that DefaultDepth in my xorg.conf file is 16, I don't understand what you think with "do you build Qt with depths"? Colors are good when there is xorg.conf file in my /etc/X11/directory but video doesn't work. When I remove xorg.conf from /etc/X11/ video starts to work, but there is a lack of colors on my LCD screen.

Comment: While building Qt there's a configuration options "-depths",  Which version of Qt you're using? and which media playback backend?

Comment: GStreamer uses xvimagesink plugin to render video frames in native X11 window, your case is that QtMultimedia fallback to render video frames on Qt widget, you'll need to set QVideoWidget to use native window handle, check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qwidget.html#native-widgets-vs-alien-widgets

Comment: Basically you need GStreamer (xvimagesink) to be aware of the widget used to render video frames, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873113/how-to-implement-a-video-widget-in-qt-that-builds-upon-gstreamer