# Qt5 VideoOverview example does not work. Any solution?

Tags: linux, qt5, gstreamer, beagleboneblack, qtmultimedia

I am stuck for a month with a video example given in [Qt Video Overview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/videooverview.html).

I tried that code, but I only got a blank square (QWidget). I am using GStreamer0.10 for media playback over Qt5. I also played a video with gst-launch-0.10 command and it works okay, but I cannot determine what's happening in Qt and why it won't work.

I looked in the error log of X Server, located in `/etc/X11/Xorg.0.log`, and when I use fbdev as a display driver configured in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` it shows me the error:

> "FBDEV(0): FBIOPUTCMAP: Invalid argument"

When I use modesetting driver everything acts the same but no errors. I figured out that when I deleted xorg.conf file and start X server again, video works but with lack of colors and with flickering. Also the example works well on my Ubuntu VM and via vnc client. Every advice and help will be appreciated.

- Target machine: BeagleBone Black
- Distribution: Debian Jessie 8.2
- Kernel Version: 4.1.15-ti-rt-r43

List of available drivers in /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers: **ati_drv.so, mach64_drv.so, nouveau_drv.so, r128_drv.so, vesa_drv.so, fbdev_drv.so, modesetting_drv.so, omap_drv.so, radeon_drv.so**

Here is a full error log from Xorg when I try to launch my Qt application on BeagleBone Black under Debian Jessie 8.2 -> http://pastebin.com/4x8KztBk

xorg.conf file from /etc/X11 -> http://pastebin.com/4WhX8pJc

Comment: If you just need a mediaplayer, [qt-vlc](https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt) might be better.

Comment: @Thomas I will post everything you need, just say.

Comment: I posted update @Thomas

Comment: Maybe this can help you? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#native-widgets-vs-alien-widgets

Comment: @arrowd I tried **export  QT_USE_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1**, but the same behavior.

Comment: @Lazar Another try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873113/how-to-implement-a-video-widget-in-qt-that-builds-upon-gstreamer

Comment: @arrowd It's not a problem just with a GStreamer but also with embedded MPlayer into QWidget. Anything related to video is a problem when used inside Qt5.

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/debugging-xorg-4175575482/ Veryinteresting answer.

Comment: Try a modern version of gstreamer. 0.10 is old and may  well not be the version the Qt wants. Lot of issues of 0.10 have been fixed in the newer version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530362/playing-a-network-streaming-video-using-qt-multimedia-and-widgets Refer this..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448027/play-a-live-video-stream-using-qt This may help you

Comment: What was the Linux kernel level on the machine it isn't operating?

Answer (score 0):

It's an incompatibility between the versions of Qt5 and libGStreamer0.10.

You need libgstreamer1.0-0 (1.22.0-2), and gstreamer1.0-qt5 (1.22.0-5) plugin, and also you may need gtk+3.

gst-plugins built from gst-plugins-good1.0 (1.22.0-5). See: https://packages.debian.org/sid/gstreamer1.0-qt5