# How to add a gstreamer 1.0 video element to a qt5 app

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gstreamer

I'm trying to play video in a Qt widget on linux.

[How to implement a video widget in Qt that builds upon GStreamer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873113/how-to-implement-a-video-widget-in-qt-that-builds-upon-gstreamer)

The above question is pretty close to what I want, but 6 years old. `QApplication::syncX();` no longer exists in qt5 so I dropped that. I've also changed `gst_x_overlay_set_xwindow_id()` to `gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle` for the gstreamer version change.

My pipeline works if I don't pass any window handle to the video sink (it just pops up a new window with the video). I'm not sure if I'm missing something to get it to render inside of Qt though.

---

### EDIT

I can set the entire app window as the overlay, but not a subsection of the main widget. Also, couldn't get the appsink working, but glimagesink seems to work.

```
// QWidget* widget = QApplication::activeWindow(); // this works
QWidget* widget = new QWidget(ui->base_widget); // this doesn't work
widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NativeWindow, true);
widget->resize(320,240);
widget->update();
widget->setStyleSheet("background-color: red");
widget->show();
winId = widget->winId();
QApplication::sync();
gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(sink) , winId);
```

Comment: It's better to post some of your code to show what is missing.

Answer (score 3):

If the purpose here is to just render video you can use `autovideosink` which will create a suitable window for you and you would not need to worry about handling this manually.

However if you still want to render this on a widget window say, try the `appsink`, read the frames on the sink and use the `onPaint` event in your widget to render the frames. Just be sure the frames are in format which can be rendered like RGB you can do that via the `videoconvert` or ensure format via the `capsfilter`. You might also be able to use `glimagesink` and pass that your window id to render the frames.

if you want to render the video on a `qvideowidget` using `appsink` as mentioned above you could try:

```
video_widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NativeWindow, true);
WId win_id = video_widget->winId();
QApplication::sync();
gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_X_OVERLAY(data->appsink), win_id);
```

Comment: Thanks Samer, I'll try out appsink.  What is this onPaint event you are suggesting me use? A cursory googling has failed me. Are there any references that I could check out.

Comment: onPaint was using a Canvas type. See here for more details: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html. The quickest way would be to use a qvideowidget with the code I pasted above. That allows you to link your videowidget with the appsink.

Comment: I'm still having a little trouble getting everything working, might come back to ask you a couple more questions if that's okay with you Samer =)

Comment: Sure thing, thats why we are all here ;)

Comment: I couldn't find gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle but I do have gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle. is gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle still part of gstreamer 1.0?

Comment: I got it working for OSX but have been having trouble on linux.

Comment: gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle is gst 0.10, however you can use the alternate, gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle. There is a Qt example in the documentation: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-gstvideooverlay.html. What problems are you having?

Comment: The video doesn't render. I see a black square.

Comment: What do the connected elements look like? Try adding a color space filter?

Comment: right now its just "videotestsrc ! glimagesink". What would a color space filter do?

Comment: Rendering problems are generally related to color space that's why, I remember seeing this along time back. Can you try videotestsrc !  "video/x-raw, format=xyz" ! glimagesink
where xyz can be replaced with RGB, RGBA, YV12, NV12, I420, YUY2, UYVY